# Using "and" in return

Tags: python, methods, python-2.7, return

I'm taking Web Application Engineering course on Udacity. I noticed that the instructor use `and` operator in `return` statement in his validation method. And I didn't understand how it is possible to return 2 arguments. I think, it may be something like `if` statement. Could  anyone explain what it actually is?

Here is the validation method:

```
USER_RE = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20}$")
def valid_username(username):
    return username and USER_RE.match(username)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `return a and b` means `return (a and b)` i.e. `x = a and b; return x`

Comment: As the answers below indicate, this isn't returning two arguments. However, in Python, it's very easy to return a tuple of two items, which can be useful in other contexts.

Comment: Another way to write it: `return USER_RE.match(username) if username else username`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `and` operator evaluates whether both of its arguments are tru-ish, but in a slightly surprising way:  First it examines its left argument.  If it is truish, then it returns its right argument.  If the left argument is falsish, then it returns the left argument.

So the last line in your code:

```
return username and USER_RE.match(username)
```

is the same as:

```
if username:
    return USER_RE.match(username)
else:
    return username
```

Strings like `username` are truish if they are not empty.  The regex `match` function returns a truish match object if the pattern matches, and returns `None`, a falsish value, if it doesn't match.

The net result is that `valid_username` will return a truish value if username is not an empty string, and the username matches the given pattern.

Note the "and" here has nothing to do with returning two values, it's computing one value.

Answer (score 3):

When you use a logical operator, it continues according to the rules, so with and, it evaluates the truthiness of the first statement and if it isn't truthy, it returns a non-truthy value (in the first case, '').

```
print repr("" and "THIS IS POST AND")
""

print "" or "THIS IS POST AND"
THIS IS POST AND

print None or "Something else"
Something else
```

Where this comes in handy is when you don't want to call a non-existent method on something like `None` (e.g. the length trait):

```
r = None

s = [1,2,3,4]

print r and len(r)
None

print s and len(s)
4
```

In the case you posted, the point is that you only want to check the username against the regular expression if the username is truthy.

It's important to note here that `and`, and `or` both short-circuit.  So if you get something non-truthy, the function won't even evaluate the regular expression.

Answer (score -1):

`and` is just a binary operator. `return a and b` is structurally the same as `return a + b` or `return a * b`, and works the same way. The expression is evaluated, then its result is given to `return`, which returns it to the caller. There is nothing at all special about using `and` in a `return` statement.

As explained very well by Ned's answer, the result of `a and b` is true-ish if both of `a` and `b` are true-ish, and false-ish otherwise. It also short-circuits if the left argument is false-ish, since that is sufficient to determine the result of the whole `a and b` expression.

In this case, an empty string would not match that regular expression, so the operation is redundant considered purely as logic. I strongly suspect though that it's being used here because `username` might be given the value `None`, which would cause the regular expression match to throw an exception. Using `username and USER_RE.match(username)` rather than just `USER_RE.match(username)` means that any false-ish value (including `None`) for `username` causes the function to return something false-ish without even attempting the regular-expression match.

But again, this has nothing to do with `return`, it's just how `and` works.